# How to make a test data for full length of definition?

Tags: excel

## How to make a test data for full length of definition ?

Thanks for your replies to my threads.

I am looking to make a test data to satisfy the full length of field definition.

For instance, with this data structure:

```
Name varchar (10)
Business Name varchar (15)
Address Varchar (20)

there are many more fields around 70-80 after above sample
```

Test file to be with '|' delimiter

```
xxxxxxxxxx|uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu|pppppppppppppppppppp
```

The above is a sample. The fields can be filled with fake characters

If Numeric like number (9,2) with digits

If character like varchar like varchar(20) mix of alphabets & digits

some files use ASCII '\031' as delimiter.

I tried to do this with excel, unix tools, but I couldn't figure it out. I need forum's guidance.

The awk code given below, how to add different record structure & ASCII '\031' as delimiter?

Am I able to do the above ?

How do I do that?

Thanks for your guidance.

UPDATE:

Thanks for sharing the code. I did test the posted code. It makes the desired output.

If I want to improve this code to make random(FAKE) characters instead of 'x', 'p', 'u', what are linux commands do this? The desired output look like.

12x        15u                8z       6y   12q
xxxxxxxxxxxx|uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu|zzzzzzzz|yyyyy|qqqqqqqqqqqq
AbXyTruxMgYu|ioPkLmByKuYnBgFr|DcMdWeqo|pnBBv|xmvbghYYueIr

I need to make some digits as well like 923456.4532 etc based on data type

How do we use

openssl rand
gpw

in this script?

We are using the '|' field separator in this script. If I want to change this to ASCII \031 (\031 ^Y EM end of medium (?!)), will changing  Sep = "^Y"; work ?

Thanks for sharing.

Comment: To generate the string above, you could use shell syntax such as `echo "xxxxxxxxxx|uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu|pppppppppppppppppppp|"`. If that is not what you want, please make your request clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added some clarification to my question and improvement of output requirement such as random, \031 field separator etc.

Answer (score 0):

This awk generates variable-length strings.

```
#! /bin/bash

Str () {

    Awk='
function Str (v, n, Local, x) {

    x = sprintf ("%*s", n, "");
    gsub (/./, v, x);
    return (x);
}
{ printf ("%s|%s|%s|\n", Str( "x", 12), Str( "u", 15), Str( "p", 8)); }
'
    echo | awk "${Awk}"
}

    Str

$ ./Str
xxxxxxxxxxxx|uuuuuuuuuuuuuuu|pppppppp|
$
```

It is not particularly efficient for large files. It could pre-generate, say, an array of 26 strings of 1000 characters in a BEGIN section, and then print subsections of those with the format `%.*s` using the required length and an index to the letter needed. Then it could read individual input specifications for those lines like `20 d 16 z 42 q` to tailor each line to your requirements. Like this (tested on GNU/awk 4.1.4, results not shown):

```
#! /bin/bash

Str () {

    Awk='
BEGIN {
    Sep = "|";
    split ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", C, "");
    for (j in C) X[C[j]] = Str( C[j], 1000);
}
function Str (v, n, Local, x) {

    x = sprintf ("%*s", n, "");
    gsub (/./, v, x);
    return (x);
}
{ 
    for (f = 1; f < NF; f += 2) {
        printf ("%.*s%s", $(f), X[$(1 + f)], Sep);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
'
    awk "${Awk}"
}

    Str <<'EOF'
12 x 15 u 8 z 
6 y 12 q
EOF
```

I'm not clear where Excel comes in. If you need the results in Excel, you will need to import as CSV.